# Poset-troids …?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, posets, matroid-theory

In many respects,

> spanning tree : graph :: linear extension : poset

For instance, the number of spanning trees/linear extensions is a measure of the "richness" or "complexity" of the graph/poset. Also, the collection of all the spanning trees/linear extensions determines the graph/poset.

(Okay if the graph is not connected we should say "spanning forest" instead of "spanning tree"; but the tree terminology is more common.)

The collection of spanning trees of a graph (thought of as subsets of edges) is a prototypical example of a matroid. Indeed, the notion of matroid can be seen as an *abstraction* of this kind of collection.

**Question**: Has anyone ever defined/investigated a "matroid-like" abstraction of the collection of linear extensions of a poset? E.g., collections of permutations of size $n$ satisfying some compatibility condition?

A wildly optimistic guess would be that these could be related to the full flag variety in the way that matroids are related to Grassmannians; however, I take it that "flag matroids" already have an established meaning in this context, which at first glance does not appear to be related to what I am asking (see e.g. [Cameron, Dinu, Michałek, and Seynnaeve - Flag matroids: algebra and geometry](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.00272)).

Comment: It seems maybe posets corresponding to “braid cones” and braid cones are unions of Weyl chambers (each of which correspond to a linear extension) might be in the direction of what you want?

Comment: @JohnMachacek: Yes, I like this idea, but then every such poset-troid would be realizable as the set of linear extensions of a poset, right?

Comment: I guess it would depend on how we define poset-troids. I don't know what would be the correct definition with good properties. I could see it being something like: *a collection of Weyl chambers that is connected in codim 1*. This should include "realizable" poset-troids (coming from posets) plus some new things.

Comment: Is there determinant or smth. like that formula for the number of linear extensions, like it exists for spanning trees? I know it only for skew Young tableaux. I am afraid that counting linear extensions is computationally hard even for finite subsets of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ (Igor Pak proved smth in this direction, I forgot exact formulation), so unlikely it exists, determinants are computationally ok. Maybe we should either restrict to some classes of posets, or modify the richness measure.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: right, although I do think it's fair to say that # of spanning trees/linear extensions are both measures of "complexity", there is a major difference between them that I'm eliding in that counting spanning trees is (computationally) easy while counting linear extensions is hard.

Comment: If you take a finite poset with a natural labeling, the set of linear extensions will be a down-set in the symmetric group with the weak Bruhat order.  (I believe it will be a principal down-set if the poset is two-dimensional.)  I would like to know how to characterize the down-sets that arise.

Comment: @Tri: that's a very nice observation/question!

Comment: Agreed: I wonder if there is some notion of closure, which, given a collection of permutations on [n], gives you (unless the collection is "inconsistent" in some fashion) a 
 naturally-labeled poset whose linear extensions includes the original collection (and the "smallest" such set of linear extensions).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of anything exactly along the lines of your question.  It really depends on what properties you're hoping to generalize.

Here's one direction in which one can generalize.  [Promotion and evacuation](https://doi.org/10.37236/75) are operations on the set of linear extensions of a poset.  These operations can be formulated in a more general setting, as Stanley explains in his paper.

Your mention of the relationship between matroids and Grassmannians suggests that you might find the concept of [Coxeter matroids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_matroid) interesting, but I don't think Coxeter matroids can plausibly be considered to be generalizations of the set of linear extensions of an arbitrary poset.

Comment: Thanks Timothy! Indeed, the question is vague, and what I'm "hoping" to generalize is unclear to me as well. The generalization of promotion/evacuation from Stanley's survey is very nice. I think the "flag matroids" which I mentioned in the question are a special case of Coxeter matroids, and as you said it's not clear that they're related to linear extension.